# Three spans in a div, right most span take all width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a form with 3 `<input>`s and one textarea below. All of them are inside a container. The 2 first `<input>`s have min and max width and a % the 3rd input has min and % but no max width.
I would like that when I make the window big enough so that the 1st and 2nd reach their max width, the 3rd one grows to 100% instead of staying limited to 45% and the rest staying in spaces.

**HTML:**

```css
.container{
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form{
  text-align: center;
}
#text{
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
#iName{
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 45px;
  max-width: 70px;
}
#iDate{
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
#iTitle{
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="form" class="form">
    <input id="iDate" value="28/03/2017 13:19"></input>
    <input id="iName" value="Jhon"></input>
    <input id="iTitle" value="My title"></input><br>
    <textarea id="text" rows="4" cols="50">
     Some Text
    </textarea><br>
    <button id="update">Update</button>
  </div>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: `<input />` are a self closing tag

Comment: can you change the structure of the html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great case scenario to use `flexbox`. 
https://jsfiddle.net/2nfo8exr/

As you can see, you can still set the `min-width` and `max-width` restrictions, but it will make sure to *use all of the remaining space* on that 3rd input to fill up the width.

Also please notice `input` tags are self-closed and you don't need `</input>` as that's not valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. And thank you all who tried to respond the question and the feedback about <input>.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solves the problem (if I understand the problem correctly).

```
#iTitle {
    /*
    where 95% is the width of textarea
    where 150px + 70px is the max width of the other inputs
    where -12px is the space (4px * 3) in between div elements
    */
    width: calc(95% - (150px + 70px) - 12px);
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the pure code you can use it without any addition

**HTML**

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="form" class="form">
      <input id="iDate" value="28/03/2017 13:19">
      <input id="iName" value="Jhon">
      <input id="iTitle" value="My title"><br>
      <textarea id="text" rows="4">ASfadfasbncaksjb</textarea>
     <br />
     <button id="update">Update</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.form {
  text-align: center;
}

#text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 98%;
}
#iName {
  width: 15%;
}
#iDate {
  width: 40%;
}
#iTitle {
  width: 40%;
}
```